# OLS with constraint

Tags: matrices, regression

Given a OLS regression problem
$$
Y = \beta X + \epsilon
$$
its analytical solution is given by
$$
\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY
$$
What constraints should I put on X or how should I define/transform X so that,
$$
(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \ge 0
$$
What will be the analytical solution of the resulting regression problem?

Note that X is non-square (M x N) matrix.